# How to save images only custom album in iphone photlibrary?

Tags: ios, iphone, photolibrary

I have one doubt, Is it possible to save the image only on custom album not in savedphotosalbum in iPhone photolibrary. Because this guy told every image must be stored on camera roll or saved photos album default. That link is below,

[Saving image to custom album only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113361/saving-image-to-custom-album-only)

Guys can you give some suggestion or new idea to store the image only custom album name.

If any one give I really appreciate to you.

Comment: i think this is possible  check this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954380/save-photos-to-custom-album-in-iphones-photo-library

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this isn't possible, all images appear both in the camera roll and in the album you save them to. If you still insist on the images not appearing in the camera roll you can create and manage your own gallery within the app (using `Core Data` for instance). I really wouldn't recommend this as there's a lot of overhead in maintaining such a gallery (speaking from experience).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    [library saveImage:image toAlbum:@"Your Album" withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error) {
            if (error!=nil) {
                NSLog(@"Big error: %@", [error description]);
            }
        }];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Kindly go through the following link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113361/saving-image-to-custom-album-only